# sc.exe is not returning output

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created a PowerShell script for changing password for Windows services.
Using `sc.exe` in code for the same.
When I execute the script it changed password in few servers but failed for others.
Next, I executed the command directly on the servers to check. The command is not returning anything.

On servers where it was successful, it will return a success message or some error if the password in not changed or if command not proper.
Also, same command is used with same values in all servers. Following is the command:

```
sc.exe config "$Service" obj= "$UserName" password= "$Password"
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you're running where and how. I don't see anything inherently wrong with the command itself.

Comment: An alternative you can try is the [Change()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx) method of the WMI `Win32_Service` class.  I'd usually only call an external program if there was no other alternative - using cdmlets, .NET, WMI, etc, are usually always a better way to go.

Comment: I tried using WMI. Problem is it is disabled and cannot enable same due to customer policies. 
This is basically for Backup Exec tool. There are some other stuff also which has to be done using powershell, that is why using the same.

Comment: You forgot to include the error codes you're observing in `$LastExitCode`. Without that, I don't see how anyone can help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: As @eryksun said, you can observe whether `sc.exe` is successful by checking `$LastExitCode` after executing the command.  It should be zero.  That is extremely bizarre they have WMI disabled.  Don't they have any network monitoring or reporting?

Comment: Thanks Guys..will check the $LastExitCode and proceed further.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help. This was because some servers were DC servers on which execution of sc.exe was restricted. It is working fine on other servers.